# Portable Library referenced by Windows Store App: MSB3815: Satellite assembly was built improperly

Tags: embedded-resource, portable-class-library

I uses VS2012 Prof (Update 3 RC-2).

I have a Portable Libray (Windows Store Apps + .Net Framework 4.5 + Windows Phone 8)
that has some string Resource files in it.
The files are named "XYZ.resx" for the default language and "XYZ.DE.resx" for german.
The Properties for the resource files are set as this:

- Build Action: "Embedded Resource"
- Copy To Output Directory: "Do not copy"
- Custom Tool: "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator"
- Custom Tool Namespace: "empty"
- File Name: "XYZ.DE.resx"
- Full Path: ""

If I build the Portable Library alone, I get no errors.
If I reference it from my Windows Store app I get some build error messages:

> MSB3815: Satellite assembly "D:\sources\Clients\Infrastructure.Services\bin\Debug\DE\Infrastructure.Services.resources.dll" was built improperly. The manifest resource "Infrastructure.Services.Localization.CarbonDioxideStateRes.DE.resources" will not be found by the ResourceManager.  It must end in ".de.resources".

So the Windows Store App doesn't like the way the Protable Library builds the resources.
What do I need to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug and will be fixed in a future version of Visual Studio. You can use Daniel's workaround (lower-casing the "DE") until you have the fix.

Comment: That did the trick. I needed to remove and re added the renamed resource files in order to compile the WinRt project.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it may not like the capitalization of the resources file.  Can you try renaming it to end in ".de.resources" instead of ".DE.resources"?